# iPhone Numeric Keypad with Decimal for web apps on a editable DIV

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html

I built a webapp for mobile.

My DOM has a `<div contenteditable="true">` which triggers a keyboard showing up on iOS on touch into the container. So far so good, but in the particular case, I want the user to enter numbers with decimals, so I would like to trigger a numpad with decimal support on iOS (on all mobile broswers later).

Can anyone tell me how to CSS or attribute my container to get the desired numpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should replace your current input tag with the following one

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

That's actually telling iOS (and Android) browser to use the large numpad.

For more details see [here](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/better-numerical-inputs-for-mobile-forms/).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question just because @wzr1337 chose to accept it. Using a number type introduces new problems for instance what if you don't want a spinner (webkit) or you want a consistent look and feel cross browser.