# Android and iOS: How to show numeric keypad on contenteditable divs?

Tags: javascript, html

On an input field it's easy. But how to bring the numeric keyboard up on a div that is contenteditable.

The question has been asked here [iPhone Numeric Keypad with Decimal for web apps on a editable DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792591/iphone-numeric-keypad-with-decimal-for-web-apps-on-a-editable-div). But the answer talks about replacing the div with input. I need to make it work on the div. Any suggestions?